# Sails Js - how i can make an automated task

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, sails.js

I want make an automated task inside sails, this task should check some variables in db and do something but.. idk how to make it, i search about grunt task, but nothing usefull. Anyone now how i can make an automated task without interaction with client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it isn't trigger by your client why don't you use another script run by cron(or any other task schedular program).

Comment: and how i can use waterline?

Comment: What do you mean waterline?

Comment: waterline its db, how i can get some data from db?

Comment: your answer made me think on another ways to resolve this like:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34435205/sails-js-how-i-can-watch-file-directory